# Why is Hashkiveinu not considered a hefsek between Ga'al Yisra'el and the Amidah (Chabad)?

Tags: minhag, shemoneh-esrei, chabad, maariv, leil-shabbat

Read this first: [Veshameru in Chabad siddur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8648/11486)

**TL;DR**

Many recite Veshamru (Shemot 31:16) before the Amidah in the Friday night Ma'ariv service. The custom in Chabad, however, is to not recite this paragraph. The reason is because the bracha of Ga'al Yisra'el and the Amidah ought to be connected, with no hefsek (interruption) between.

---

If the bracha of Ga'al Yisra'el and the Amidah are supposed to be connected, why is the paragraph of Hashkiveinu between the two? Doesn't this undermine Chabad's reasoning for not reciting Veshamru? Perhaps Hashkiveinu is considered to be an extension of Ga'al Yisra'el and therefore not a hefsek?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93905/13438), the Talmud states that *Hashkiveinu* is not an interruption between *geulah* and *tefillah* because since it was ordained by the Sages as part of the blessings for *Keriat Shema* it is as if it is an extended *geulah*.

[Berachot 4b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=4b&format=pdf)

> דאי לא תימא הכי שחרית היכי מצי סמיך והא אמר רבי יוחנן בתחלה אומר ה׳
>   שפתי תפתח ולבסוף הוא אומר יהיו לרצון אמרי פי אלא התם כיון דתקינו רבנן
>   למימר ה׳ שפתי תפתח כתפלה אריכתא דמיא הכא נמי כיון דתקינו רבנן למימר
>   השכיבנו כגאולה אריכתא דמיא
>
> For, if you do not admit that, how can he join in the morning, seeing
>   that R. Johanan says: In the beginning [of the Tefillah] one has to
>   say: O Lord, open Thou my lips [etc.], and at the end one has to say:
>   Let the words of my mouth be acceptable? [The only explanation] there
>   [is that] since the Rabbis ordained that O Lord, open Thou my lips
>   should be said, it is like a long Tefillah. Here, too, since the
>   Rabbis ordained that ‘Let us rest’ should be said, it is like a long
>   Ge'ullah. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))